# Keras MobileNet example yields different answers on different computers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision

I have a very simple example with the Keras MobileNet implementation trying to classify a minivan. I run the same code on two different computers and get different results, not just slightly different but different enough that the classifications are not the same.

(note that Tensorflow=1.7.0 and Keras=2.1.5 on both computers)

Code below

```
import sys
import argparse
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import time
try:
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  HAS_MATPLOTLIB = True
except:
  HAS_MATPLOTLIB = False


from keras.preprocessing import image
#from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input, decode_predictions

from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet, preprocess_input, decode_predictions

#model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
model = MobileNet()
target_size = (224, 224)

def predict(model, img, target_size, top_n=3):
  """Run model prediction on image
  Args:
    model: keras model
    img: PIL format image
    target_size: (w,h) tuple
    top_n: # of top predictions to return
  Returns:
    list of predicted labels and their probabilities
  """
  if img.size != target_size:
    img = img.resize(target_size)

  print "preprocessing input.."
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  x = preprocess_input(x)
  print "making predicition..."
  preds = model.predict(x)
  print "prediction made: %s" % preds
  return decode_predictions(preds, top=top_n)[0]

if __name__=="__main__":
  a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  a.add_argument("--image", help="path to image")
  a.add_argument("--image_url", help="url to image")
  args = a.parse_args()

  if args.image is None and args.image_url is None:
    a.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

  if args.image is not None:
    img = Image.open(args.image)
    preds = predict(model, img, target_size)

  if args.image_url is not None:
    print "getting image from url"
    response = requests.get(args.image_url)
    print "image gotten from url"
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    print "predicting.."
    before = time.time()
    preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
    print "total time to predict: %.2f" % (time.time() - before)

  print preds
  plot_preds(img, preds)
```

Now if I run this on my MacBook Pro

```
$ python classify_example_mobile.py  --image_url https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpDL.jpg

[(u'n03770679', u'minivan', 0.39935172), (u'n02974003', u'car_wheel', 0.28071228), (u'n02814533', u'beach_wagon', 0.19400564)]
```

but if I then run it on another computer that I have

```
(venv) $ python classify_example_mobile.py --image_url https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpDL.jpg
[(u'n02974003', u'car_wheel', 0.39516035), (u'n02814533', u'beach_wagon', 0.27965376), (u'n03770679', u'minivan', 0.22706936)]
```

the predictions are reversed, it no longer picks minivan as the top result.

How could this be? I know that different architectures can have different floating-point math accuracy, but would that be enough to account for these results? I also know that models can vary depending on the way the weights are initialized during training, but this is a pre-trained model, so what gives?

edit  - to be clear, the image is a picture of a minivan, so in this case one architecture gets it right and the other one gets it wrong - so this is a big deal for me. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpDL.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried setting the same seed between the two scripts? E.g. `numpy.random.seed(0)`

Comment: I don't think that will make a difference since there isn't any randomness involved here - the model is pretained, the weights are set, the input data is the same between both. I'll try though and report back

Comment: confirming that it didn't make any difference, thanks for the recommendation though

Comment: I did in fact have some experience a couple of years ago when the same network worked differently on CPU and GPU. Theoretically a bug in Tensorflow is possible. Are you using the same Tensorflow and Keras versions? I'd suggest printing the activations of the first 10 neurons in each layer and compare the two networks to see where they start to diverge.

Comment: tensorflow=1.7.0 and keras=2.1.5 on both computers

Answer (score 0):

So I don't quite understand what is going on here, but the error appears to have gone away once I did some more preprocessing of the input, which makes me think that maybe I had different PIL versions of numpy versions or something.

I added these lines

```
img = img.convert("RGB")
```

and now the results between the two computers are identical

Comment: Can you file a github issue?